# Where in this code do I need to put 'return false'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the 'slide-toggle' link, my url turns from mysite.com to mysite.com/#

I was told that I needed to put a 'return false' somewhere in here but I'm not sure where. Can someone kindly help me out?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#slide-up').click(function () {
        $('.slide-container').slideUp(function(){
            $('#slide-toggle').removeClass('active');
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('a#slide-toggle').click(function() {
        var slideToggle = this;
        if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
            $('.slide-container').slideUp(function() {
                $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.slide-container').slideDown();
            $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you, please, edit your question to include the language. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be nicer not to use `return false` but to use [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) instead.  You can put this at the very top of your event handler:

```
$('a#slide-toggle').click(function(e) { // note e added as the function's parameter
    e.preventDefault();

    var slideToggle = this;
    if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
        $('.slide-container').slideUp(function() {
            $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.slide-container').slideDown();
        $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

This has the same effect as `return false`, but with the following advantages:

- It is semantically more logical -- it does what it says
- You can put it at the head of the function, so it is immediately obvious
- You can have multiple exit points without having to ensure they are all `return false`
- If any part of your code causes an error, the default action will still be prevented

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment/answer!

Comment: Using e.preventDefault() will not stop the event bubbling to other elements. You'll need to also have e.stopPropogation(). return false does exactly this.

Comment: @Luke True, but that isn't the case here. Indeed, I would suggest that that is a *bad* thing in this case, as handlers using `delegate` or somesuch would break. Furthermore, I would *always* prefer to use `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` together, rather than `return false`, for the same reasons listed in my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following but should I add `stopPropagation` in that code somewhere?

Comment: @John Only if you need to (and in this instance, I doubt you do).

Answer (score 0):

You have one at the end of `slide-up`; add one to the end of `slide-toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it should be like this:

```
$('a#slide-toggle').click(function() {
        var slideToggle = this;

        if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
            $('.slide-container').slideUp(function() {
                $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.slide-container').slideDown();
            $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
        }

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Using an empty `href` attribute will not prevent an URL change as the browser will interpret it as `href="."` or `href="/"`. Some browsers may however interpret it as no `href` attribute at all, turning the tag into a bookmark anchor instead of a link, or ignoring the tag entirely.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
    $('a#slide-toggle').click(function() {
        var slideToggle = this;
        if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
            $('.slide-container').slideUp(function() {
                $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.slide-container').slideDown();
            $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add the return false also in the *$('a#slide-toggle').click()* function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#slide-up').click(function () {
        $('.slide-container').slideUp(function(){
            $('#slide-toggle').removeClass('active');
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('a#slide-toggle').click(function() {
        var slideToggle = this;
        if ($('.slide-container').is(':visible')) {
            $('.slide-container').slideUp(function() {
                $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.slide-container').slideDown();
            $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
        }
        **return false;**
    });
});
```